# Matrix multiplication worst case, best case and average case complexity

Tags: matrix, complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is the (a) worst case, (b) best case, and (c) average case complexity of the following function which does matrix multiplication

```
for i=1 to n do
    for j=1 to n do
        C[i,j]=0
        for k=1 to n do
            C[i,j]=C[i,j]+A[i,k]*B[k,j]
        end {for}
    end {for}
end {for}
```

How would you justify the complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i`, `j` and `k` all go from `1` to `n`.

Therefore the best, average, and worst cases are **O(n * n * n) = O(n^3)**

For each of the `n` possible `i`s, there are `n` `j`s and for each of the `n` `j`s, there are `n` `k`s. 
Which gives `n * n * n` executions of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

**O(n^3)**, because on each of the nested loop, N is multiplied by N, since you have a nested loop 3 times which completely process the entire N, that will be **N X N X N = N^3**